# Custom Binary Search Tree, inOrder not working and need input,

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

Let me start off by saying that this is a homework project, I am a student.  Now that that's out of the way I would like some input regarding my assignment, we were told to create our own BST.  I have written the code and I can't seem to find out why it is not giving me the correct output.  I know it's wrong but I don't know how it's wrong.  This is a beginning version of my code so my methods are named a bit weirdly.  Thanks for your help.

```
private BTNode<T> root;
private int maxHeight;
private int numberOfNodes;

@Override
public int getMaxHeight() {
    return maxHeight;
}

@Override
public int getNodeCount() {

    return numberOfNodes;
}



@Override
public BTNode<T> getRoot() {

    return root;
}
```

// This is where I believe the problem is starting.

```
@Override
public BTNode<T> insert(T rec) {
    BTNode<T> node = new BTNode<T>();
    if (isEmpty()) {
        root = node;
        root.setRecord(rec);
        root.setHeight(0);
    } else
        node = insertify(rec, root);
    numberOfNodes++;

    return node;
}



private BTNode<T> insertify(T rec, BTNode<T> node) {
    int TVal = Integer.parseInt(rec.toString());
    int Nodevalue = Integer.parseInt(node.getRecord().toString());
    BTNode<T> newnode = null;

    if (TVal < Nodevalue) {
        if (node.hasLeft())
            this.insertify(rec, node.getLeft());
        else {
            newnode = new BTNode<T>();
            node.setLeft(newnode);

            newnode.setRecord(rec);
            newnode.setParent(node);
            newnode.setHeight(newnode.getParent().getHeight() + 1);


            if (newnode.getHeight() > maxHeight)
                maxHeight = newnode.getHeight();

        }


    } else if (TVal > Nodevalue) {
        if (node.hasRight())
            this.insertify(rec, node.getRight());
    } else {
        newnode = new BTNode<T>();
        node.setRight(newnode);

        newnode.setRecord(rec);
        newnode.setParent(node);
        newnode.setHeight(newnode.getParent().getHeight() + 1);


        if (newnode.getHeight() > maxHeight)
            maxHeight = newnode.getHeight();
        return newnode;
    }

    return newnode;

}


@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {

    if (root == null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


ArrayList<T> inorder = new ArrayList<T>();

private void inordertra(BTNode<T> node) {
    if (node.hasLeft()) {
        inordertra(node.getLeft());
    }

    inorder.add(node.getRecord());

    if (node.hasRight()) {
        inordertra(node.getRight());
    }
}

@Override
public String toStringInorder(BTNode<T> v) {
    String s = "";
    inorder.clear();
    inordertra(root);

    for (int i = 0; i < inorder.size(); i++) {
        s =  s + inorder.get(i);
    } 
    System.out.print(s);
    return s;
}

}
```

When I create a new instance of BST and insert a bunch of integer values then call the toStringinorder method, I simply get 1 3 as output.  This is after I inserted 3,5,1,7,6 in that order.  For some reason it's not giving me all the numbers I passed to it.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a closing curly brace in the wrong place.

Left as a homework to the original poster to figure out where it is.  If I can find it just by eyeballing the code on my phone, you should surely be able to figure it out with the aid of a single step debugger.

Also, if the data is supposed to be generic, don't try to treat it as if it will always be inter convertible to Integer.  Use a Comparator< T > instead of assuming "less than" operator works.

Finally, the following code is just appalling:

```
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (root == null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Why not

```
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null;
}
```